# SASS : Generated CSS not optimal with loop

Tags: css, loops, sass

I'm trying to generate optimal CSS with a @for loop in SASS.

An example is better than words :

My SASS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .table-lg-#{$i}, .table-md-#{$i}, .table-sm-#{$i}, .table-xs-#{$i} {
        background:red;
    }
}
```

What SASS generates:

```
.table-lg-1, .table-md-1, .table-sm-1, .table-xs-1 {
  background: red;
}

.table-lg-2, .table-md-2, .table-sm-2, .table-xs-2 {
  background: red;
}
```

What I would like SASS to generate :

```
.table-lg-1, .table-md-1, .table-sm-1, .table-xs-1, .table-lg-2, .table-md-2, .table-sm-2, .table-xs-2 {
  background: red;
}
```

Do you have any solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a silent class and `extend` it inside of the `for` loop.

```
%background-color {
  background: red;
}

@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  .table-lg-#{$i}, .table-md-#{$i}, .table-sm-#{$i}, .table-xs-#{$i} {
        @extend %background-color;
    }
}
```

[Here's a gist](http://sassmeister.com/gist/a564770de5d44f7cabc3).